# why record value in mysql innodb table is replaced unexpected?

Tags: mysql, innodb

> server OS: centos 5.6
>
> mysql server:5.6.16

I create a table:

```
create table test (
    id int  auto_incremented not null,
    value int);
```

and insert into it a record such as

```
insert into test values(100001,15);
```

but next day I find (100001,15) does not exist,

but (100001,18) exists.

the table has no triggers , no foreign key.

I scanned the binlog and found the inserting statement, but found no (100001,15) related statments. What happened?

Comment: Do you ever use the `REPLACE` statement?  Does the table have a `PRIMARY KEY`?  Why do you explicitly provide `id`?  Is this part of a Cluster?

Comment: I did not find the replace statment in binlog. The table has a primary key id auto_increment. And I could not find replace statement in slave's binlog(not relay log).

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen, MySQL supports **ACID**, mean your data will not change automatically, until there is the trigger or modified by some application query. See the ACID for your reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html

Hope, It will help you to understand properly ACID properties.

Comment: I can find insert statement in binlog, so the insert action is committed. I can not trace the update operation in binlog,no update occured.

Comment: Then NO IDEA what exactly happening, you can try one more day. or just insert the record again and restart the server, and check it again.